# Redirect to db table stored link

Tags: php, html, mysqli, hyperlink

I need to redirect the clicked link on stored link in database table. For e.g i clicked on a link,It should redirect me to the stored link i.e http://www.hp.com. But it is redirecting to http://localhost/Store_brand/www.hp.com. How to do this?

**Code**

```
 <?php
   $q="SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id WHERE c.c_date_entered <= CURDATE() AND c.c_date_entered >= DATE(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)) LIMIT 3";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$q);
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ?>
<a class="col-sm-4 tab url" href="<?php echo $row['sm_link'] ?>">
<div class="media">
<div class="media-left media-middle">
<img src="<?php echo $row['cat_image'] ?>" alt=""></div>
<div class="media-body">
  <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $row['c_name'] ?></h4>
  <p><?php echo $row['c_description'] ?></p>
    </div> </div>
   </a>
  <?php
   }
   ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide me with one line from the Database where it's trying to grab the information from?

Comment: @FluxCoder i have edited and added an image,

Comment: @tabia, try my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$h = strpos($row['sm_link'],'http');    
<a class="col-sm-4 tab url" href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE) ? $row['sm_link'] : "http://".$row['sm_link'] ?>">
```

You need to check if there is http or https added to URL!